# `pthread_mutex_t`, `sem_t` in a `std::map`

Tags: c++, concurrency, stl, pthreads

Basically I'm maintaining a set of states for a bunch of objects:

```
#define SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE int
std::map< SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE , bool > is_object_valid;
```

And I need to protect **each element** in `is_object_valid` with their respective `mutex_t`(Rather than a big lock). As valid values of `SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE` are *sparse* (say, dozens of values ranging from 0 to 10000000 ), a `std::map` is prefered over `std::vector`, C-style array, etc.

I'm trying to achieve something like:

```
std::map< SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE , pthread_mutex_t > mutex_array;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. (Well, data race may occur when `std::map` is being updated).

So what's the best way to achieve this? Must I write a thread-safe subscription allocator that maps `SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE` into consecutive integers so that I can store the `mutex_t`s in an array?

Comment: What's the problem with map-wide lock?

Comment: @zch Eh, Not efficient enough. Part of the program depends on Remote Procedure Call, therefore blocking several threads unnecessarily is too expensive.

Comment: You're not showing enough code to really diagnose, but I have some guesses: When you "insert" a mutex into the map you are really creating a new one.  So you need to initialize it and lock it.  The mutex you copied from is now useless.  So make sure that you aren't sometimes locking the original and sometimes the one in the map.

Comment: @WanderingLogic He should be able to defer initializing the mutex in the map until it is actually in the map.  Something like `std::pair<Map::iterator, bool> r = myMap.insert( make_pair<int, pthread_mutex_t>( newKey, pthread_mutex_t() ) ); assert( r.second ); pthread_mutex_init( &r.first->second, NULL );`  Of course, he must hold the global lock on the map during this entire sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple threads reading and writing to the `mutex_array`, you will need another mutex to guard it.

Are you sure you will have multiple threads writing to the `mutex_array`?

The other thing is, instead of having two maps, you can have a `map<subscription_type, object_struct>`

```
struct object_struct {
   bool valid;
   pthread_mutex_t mutex;
};
```

And then have a single overarcing mutex to guard that map.

Comment: As soon as there are multiple threads accessing the map, and at least one is writing to it, _all_ of the threads need to protect access.

Comment: Also, of course: he can't call `pthread_mutex_init` on the mutex until it is actually in place in the map.  (At least according to Posix.  _If_ the mutex is to be initialized using the default values, I find it difficult to believe that always copying a `pthread_mutex_t initializer = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` wouldn't work, as long as you didn't try to use it until it was inserted.

Answer (score 2):

If any thread is modifying the map itself (inserting, etc.), you
need to protect all accesses to the map.  After that: if the
member is just a `bool`, how much processing can you be doing on
it that adding this time to the time the map level mutex is held
would change anything.

Otherwise: if you need a mutex per object, the simple solution
would be to put them into same object as the one on the map.
But it `mutex_t` copyable?  `pthread_mutex_t` and `std::mutex`
aren't.  This could make the insertion code overly complex,
since you can't initialize the `pthread_mutex_t`, or construct
the `std::mutex`, before the object is inserted.  (In C++11, you
could use `emplace` to solve this problem; contents of a map
don't have to be copyable if you use `emplace`.)  In C++03, 
however, you'll have to separate allocation from initialization;
the `struct` which contains your mapped value and the mutex will
in fact have to be declared with raw memory for the mutex, and
then placement new used to initialize it using the iterator you
get back from `insert`.